# Android4OpenCV: setting resolution at startup

Tags: java, opencv, android

I'm using [Android4OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) to do some live image processing, and I'd like to use the smallest resolution the camera can offer. The default resolution is the largest the camera can offer.

I'm looking at the [3rd example](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), which allows the user to change resolutions via a menu. I'd like to modify that example to change the resolution at startup instead of requiring the user go through the menu. To do that, I simply add two lines to the otherwise empty `onCameraViewStarted()` function:

```
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    android.hardware.Camera.Size res = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList().get(mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList().size()-1);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(res);
}
```

And the thing is, this works perfectly fine on my Galaxy Nexus, running Android 4.2.2. The app starts up, and the resolution is set correctly.

However, when I run the exact same app on a Nexus 7 tablet, running Android 5.1, the app hangs on the call to `setResolution()`. Actually it works okay one time, but then hangs the second time you try to run it- even if you completely exit the app, remove it from the running apps, or restart the device. Other users are reporting the same error as well, so it's not just the Nexus 7 device- in fact, my Galaxy Nexus seems to be the only device where this works.

Specifically, the application goes into the `setResolution()` function, which then calls `org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView.disconnectCamera()`, which looks like this:

**(Note: this code is internal to the OpenCV4Android library, this is not my code)**

```
protected void disconnectCamera() {
    /* 1. We need to stop thread which updating the frames
     * 2. Stop camera and release it
     */
    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnecting from camera");
    try {
        mStopThread = true;
        Log.d(TAG, "Notify thread");
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Wating for thread");
        if (mThread != null)
            mThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mThread =  null;
    }

    /* Now release camera */
    releaseCamera();
}
```

Looking at the logs, I can see that the thread gets stuck on the `synchronized(this)` line. The only other thing that synchronizes on that Object is the inner `JavaCameraView.CameraWorker` class, which is the `mThread` variable in the above code, started by the JavaCameraView class:

**(Note: this code is internal to the OpenCV4Android library, this is not my code)**

```
private class CameraWorker implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        do {
            synchronized (JavaCameraView.this) {
                try {
                    JavaCameraView.this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (!mStopThread) {
                if (!mFrameChain[mChainIdx].empty())
                    deliverAndDrawFrame(mCameraFrame[mChainIdx]);
                mChainIdx = 1 - mChainIdx;
            }
        } while (!mStopThread);
        Log.d(TAG, "Finish processing thread");
    }
}
```

I've tried futzing with that code, changing the notify() to notifyAll(), and maintaining a List of CameraWorker threads and joining each one. But no matter what, the app still hangs at the `disconnectCamera()` call.

My questions are:

- **How can I modify the third OpenCV4Android example so that its resolution is set at startup?**
- What is causing the app to hang?
- Why does this work on some devices but not others?

Edit: I haven't received any comments or answers, so I've crossposted to the OpenCV forums [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/61485/android4opencv-setting-resolution-at-startup/).

**Edit 2**: As per cyriel's suggestion, I've tried setting the resolution after several frames have gone by:

```
int frames = 0;
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    frames++;

    if(frames == 6){
        android.hardware.Camera.Size res = mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList().get(mOpenCvCameraView.getResolutionList().size()-1);
        mOpenCvCameraView.setResolution(res);

    }

    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

However, now this gets stuck in the same exact place, even on my Galaxy Nexus, which works if I set the resolution in the `onCameraViewStarted()` function. I've tried increasing the frame count to 7 and even 100, but I always get stuck in the same place.

Answer (score 5):

The most important question in your situation is whether it's working if you don't modify the code at all - are you able to change the resolution (via menu) without crashing the app?
If yes than the answer most likely is simple - it's the same bug in OpenCV as in Windows version: before changing camera resolution or fps (and most likely any property) you need to grab at least one (use 3-5 to be sure) frame before changing this property.
If no than most likely there is nothing you can do on your own - fill the bug report and wait for comments. The only alternative is to use other library to grab frames from camera and than convert it to OpenCV object.

Comment: It does indeed work if I don't modify the code at all. I've also tried changing the resolution on the first frame, and that results in the same behavior.

Comment: So most likely it's the same bug as in Windows version. Try to change resolution after 5 frames - users most likely will not even notice this. I know it's not a perfect solution, but most likely it's the best workaround.

Comment: I've edited my question to show what happens when I try this, but this doesn't seem to fix the problem either.

Comment: Personally i would try to use different library. Just grab images using other library and convert images to OpenCV Mat objects so you can leaave rest of your code unmodified. I think that trying to solve this bug in OpenCV will take more time than just using other lib.

Comment: The problem with that is, I have an entire project I've already finished, but only when I tried to test it on other devices did I find this bug. I'm not going to go back and redo the whole project. I can't believe there isn't a way to set the resolution on startup.

Comment: I am not suggesting to rebiuld whole project - try to just use other lib only for capturing images from camera and than convert it to OpenCV Mat object and leave rest of your project without any modifications.

Comment: This also doesn't explain why the program works fine the first time, but then breaks when run a second time.